# Changing inherited parameters from super to sub class

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, subclass

I have an assignment about doctors and prescriptions. In one of the classes I am not supposed to use int reit in the constructor (a sub class), as the super class have. The hint in the assignment is that int reit should always start on 3 when the prescription is made (how many times one can use the prescription). How am I supposed to change it from int reit to 3 (as I understood from a hint from an instructor in class).

*Everythings in norwegian because we have to, hope that's okay.*
Thanks for any help!

Here is the first class:

```
public abstract class Resept {

  protected int id = 0;
  protected static int teller = 1;
  protected int pasientID = 0;
  protected int reit = 0;
  protected Legemiddel legemiddel;
  protected Lege utskrivendeLege;

  public Resept(Legemiddel legemiddel, Lege utskrivendeLege, int pasientID, int reit) {
    this.legemiddel = legemiddel;
    this.utskrivendeLege = utskrivendeLege;
    this.id = teller;
    this.reit = reit;
    this.pasientID = pasientID;
  }
}
```

Here is the next:

```
public class HvitResept extends Resept {

  public HvitResept(Legemiddel legemiddel, Lege utskrivendeLege, int pasientID, int reit) {
    super(legemiddel, utskrivendeLege, pasientID, reit);
  }
}
```

And in this next class we're not supposed to write int reit in the constructor. Reit is always 3 with a new P-resept (birth control prescription).

```
public class PResept extends HvitResept {

  public PResept(Legemiddel legemiddel, Lege utskrivendeLege, int pasientID, **int reit**) {
    super(legemiddel, utskrivendeLege, pasientID, reit);
  }
}
```

Comment: In the constructor you can just set it to equal 3. And then have a setter to change the value when needed. Or just don't set it in the constructor and have it equal 3 in the class.

Comment: just don't add int reit to the PResept constructor and call the super one with 3 instead of reit

Comment: When removing int reit from the constructor, and adding 3 to the super(...); I still get an error saying Required: Legemiddel, Lege, int, int, and that actual and formal arguments lists differ in length.

Comment: Whoever is the product/project manager or customer, tell them that it's super bad to keep your source code in a non-English syntax. Maintainability, support, internationalisation of the source - just forget about all this.

Comment: I think they want it in norwegian so we can fully understand what we are doing, based on the name we give everything.  But our course book is in english, so yeah.. Sometimes a bit frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class PResept extends HvitResept {

  public PResept(Legemiddel legemiddel, Lege utskrivendeLege, int pasientID) {
    super(legemiddel, utskrivendeLege, pasientID, 3);
  }
}
```

You can call `super(...);`with the values you desire. super will call the constructor of its parent class.

Comment: I still get an error that says:

constructor HvitResept in class HvitResept cannot be applied to given types;
public class PResept extends HvitResept {
    

  required: Legemiddel,Lege,int,int
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: Seems my file was saved in the wrong folder. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

```
public class PResept extends HvitResept {
  private static final int reit = 3;
  public PResept(Legemiddel legemiddel, Lege utskrivendeLege, int pasientID) {
    super(legemiddel, utskrivendeLege, pasientID, reit);
  }
}
```

Declaring this variable as private static and final will not occupy every time when we create new object of type PResept and also the value can't be changed due to final.